# How to get space occupied in a Redshift Cluster?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I used the below Query on a couple of Redshift Clusters to get the space occupied on the cluster.

```
SELECT sum("size") from svv_table_info ;
```

Output :

1. For superlab-eu
   **160978116 (in MB)** [ this is the Disk Space consumed ]    -->   **153.52069 (in TB)** [ when divided twice by 1024]
   But when validating with the AWS Redshift Console, it is displaying the size consumed as **155.79 TB**.
2. For pandora-in
   **102658826 (in MB)** [ this is the Disk Space consumed ]    -->   **97.90309 (in TB)** [ when divided twice by 1024]
   But when validating with the AWS Redshift Console, it is displaying the size consumed as **101.78 TB**.

---

NOTE: svv_table_info is a SYSTEM TABLE

Q1) Why is the REDSHIFT CONSOLE showing 155.79 TB as space occupied where as the above query is showing 160978116 (in MB) or 153.52069 (in TB) as cluster space occupied?

Q2) Why is it not the same on both ? what is the reason ? Is there any other way to get the exact occupied size of Cluster/Table ?

Q3) Is there a problem with 'MB to TB' conversion by dividing MB twice with 1024? If yes, how should I convert it?

Comment: it could be a difference between physical (disk) size and logical (database) size of the cluster.

Comment: This [post](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx36Y9SPHL646E1/#:~:text=A%20related%20unit%2C%20the%20tebibyte,terabyte%20is%20about%200.9095%20TiB.&text=Macintosh%20OS%20correctly%20uses%201,TERAbyte%20to%20equal%201024%20Gigabytes.) might provide some clarity